# DTO constructor argument validation and WebApi response

Tags: c#, .net, oop, asp.net-web-api2, dto

If I develop a WebApi action-method

```
[Route]
public string Put([FromBody]MyClass value)
```

is it realy bad idea to use MyClass class that has parameter validation in constructor like:

```
public MyClass(string value)
{
    if (!_pattern.IsMatch(value))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Value should match RegEx: {_pattern}", nameof(value));
}
```

So on a wrong request it throws exception from JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync that occures out of controller or action filters so I have not found the way to respond the client with real problem description from `ArgumentException` message.

Is it right that even such argument check has not place in DTO which the only allowed in WebApi and for real (domain model) MyClass should be created corresponding simple contract class without any checks at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ErrorDto with a structured message from the API. Having an [ExceptionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) to handle this is common practice.

In terms of validation feedback, you might want to have a look at [this article by Martin Fowler about avoiding to use exceptions as an approach to validation](https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html).

That being said, you might find [this library interesting](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

Comment: Unfortunately ExceptionFilterAttribute handles only exceptions thrown from controller actions.

Comment: But "notification over exception" in validation looks meaningful.

Comment: I would avoid having business logic on ActionFilters. But you can still catch   those exceptions by adding a custom `<httpErrors>` section on your web.config

Comment: Actually I have self host OWIN (without web.config), but no matter - I already desided to separate validation from DTO.

Answer (score 1):

Btw I discovered that if Dto throws ArgumentException from constructor (out of controller) you still can use

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
[Route]
[ValidateModel]
public string Put([FromBody]MyClass value)
```

That would response to client with

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "value": [
      "Value should match RegEx: ...\r\nParameter name: value"
    ]
  }
}
```

But still it allows to notify only about the first found problem, when pure DTO with DataAnnotations specifies all.